# How can I do cross-domain put/post requests on iris couch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

see for example http://jsfiddle.net/lostinplace/fxZNx/

apparently enabling jsonp for cross-domain access turns all requests to get, but I have some cross-domain requests that I want to use to manipulate data (not necessarily building design docs)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is not officially supported in Apache CouchDB, however Iris Couch can enable my CORS patch, which I described in a similar question: [Any way to limit access to CouchDB view when JSONP is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688839/any-way-to-limit-access-to-couchdb-view-when-jsonp-is-enabled/6701581#6701581)

Just email support@iriscouch.com. The only thing to remember is that this is a third-party patch and so the API or the configuration system, etc. might change in the future.

But CORS is pretty awesome and worthwhile in my opinion.

Comment: it has since enabled (thanks!) but I'm having trouble with it